# Merging two lists into one

Tags: python, arrays, merge

## starting arrays

```
listone[1,2,3,4,5]
listtwo[a,b,c,d,e]
```

## wanted outcome

```
[1a,2b,3c,4d,5e]
```

## My Attempt

```
filename = open('Forks.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(filename)
Item =  []
Price = []
Full = []
for col in file:
    Item.append(col['Item Name'])
    Price.append(col['Price'])
for n in Item and Price:
    Full_Var = (n[Item],':', '£', n[Price])
    Full.append(Full_Var)
```

It's from a csv file with two columbs (Item_Name and Price)

Comment: "I keep getting really close" see [ask]: it's important to include your attempt. Please [edit] the question with your attempt. Also see [mre]: as it stands, your code is not executable as `listtwo` should be a list of strings

Comment: What are `1a` , `2b`? .... that is not valid Python. And a `[` without a `]`? Maybe work a bit more on your question before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily merge two lists like this:

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_two = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

merged_list = []
for i, j in zip(list_one, list_two):
    merged_list.append(str(i) + str(j))
print(merged_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for merging two list.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = ['a','b','c','d']
res = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    res.append(str(l1[i])+l2[i])
    
print(res)
```

Thanks.